# Way of showing permuations of n-elements in one column in python

Tags: python, permutation

I generate permutations of 3-elements with

```
import itertools
a = list(itertools.permutations(['a','b','c',],3))
```

and receive following output:

> [('a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'c', 'b'), ('b', 'a', 'c'), ('b', 'c', 'a'), ('c', 'a', 'b'), ('c', 'b', 'a')]

I want to make elements appear in vertical row with no brackets, commas and quotemarks:

```
abc
acb
bac
...
```

I tried to use join function

```
b=''.join(a)
```

but I received errors that

> TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, tuple found

My question is how can I make permute elements appear in column ?

Answer (score 1):

You can not use `join` with a `tuple` argument it just take `str` argument , So you can use a list comprehension to save in a list:

```
>>> b=[''.join(i) for i in a]
>>> b
['abc', 'acb', 'bac', 'bca', 'cab', 'cba']
>>> for i in b :
...  print i
... 
abc
acb
bac
bca
cab
cba
```

But if you just want to print , do this :

```
>>> for i in a :
...  print ''.join(i)
... 
abc
acb
bac
bca
cab
cba
```

Answer (score 1):

You got error because every element in `a` is tuple. call `''.join()` for every tuple like:

```
for item in a:
    print(''.join(item))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array = [('a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'c', 'b'), ('b', 'a', 'c'), ('b', 'c', 'a'), ('c', 'a', 'b'), ('c', 'b', 'a')]

for x in [''.join(x) for x in array]: print x
```

Comment: If you're not using that temporary list later, you'd better skip it like the other answers do.

Comment: Right but I find it easier to understand. But you are right.

Answer (score 0):

```
print '\n'.join([''.join(t) for t in itertools.permutations('abc', 3)])
```

You *could* use a generator instead of the list comprehension (i.e. get rid of the square brackets), but there's no point, since all of the strings need to exist before `'\n'.join` can do its work.

Comment: @CeesTimmerman : True, but in it's not exactly redundant code because it has an impact on performance, since generator expressions are more expensive than list comprehensions. If you use a generator expression instead of a list comprehension as the argument to `.join()` it has to generate a list from the generator expression to do its work, so it's more efficient to just supply a list comprehension.